# Conecting Existing Python class to a GUI interface

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to connect my existing Python class to a Tkinter Gui Interface, so I will be able to input variables for existing class in the gui interface. But for some reason my tkinter gui interface is not connected to my existing python class. I have done gui interfaces for python function and everything worked no problem, but with class it's a little bit tricky. It just opens the gui window when I place `df = Loan(filename = filename_text.get(), settle_date=settle_date_text.get(),  semipmts=semipmts_text.get(), share=share_text.get(), summary_dir=summary_dir_text.get())` after the mainloop or when I place it above the app code,then Python shows an error. I would appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
class Loan:
   def __init__(self, filename, settle_date, semipmts =4,share= 0, summary_dir=0):
   #read csv data
       self.data=pd.read_csv(filename)
       self.filename=filename
       self.data=self.data[['month','p','current_upb','current_interest_rate','dq']]
       self.settle_date= settle_date
       self.semipmts = semipmts
       self.summary_dir = summary_dir
   
   def get_data(self):
       self.data['Cal_Int'] = self.data['current_interest_rate']/12 *(self.data['month']+self.data['dq']+1)
       self.data['Prn'] = self.data['p']*self.data['current_upb']
       self.data['Int'] = self.data['Prn'] *self.data['Cal_Int']
       self.data['Semi Int'] = self.data['p'] * self.data['current_upb'] * self.data['current_interest_rate']/12 * self.semipmts
    
       self.data.to_csv(self.summary_dir+" summary.csv")
    
   def combined_final_grid(self):
      import glob
    
      path = self.summary_dir
    
      files=  glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
      data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
      content = []
    
      for filename in files:
         df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
         content.append(df)

  
      data_frame = pd.concat(content)
      data_frame.head()
      data_frame.to_excel(self.summary_dir + "summary.xlsx" , index=False)

app=Tk()

filename_text = StringVar()
filename_label = Label(app, text='File Path "/"', font=('bold', 12), pady=20)
filename_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
filename_entry = Entry(app, textvariable= filename_text)
filename_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
settle_date_text = StringVar()
settle_date_label = Label(app, text='Settle Date in "Y-m-d"', font=('bold', 12), pady=20)
settle_date_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
settle_date_entry = Entry(app, textvariable = settle_date_text)
settle_date_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
semipmts_text = DoubleVar()
semipmts_label = Label(app, text='   Pmts Frequency "/"', font=('bold', 12))
semipmts_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
semipmts_entry = Entry(app, textvariable= semipmts_text)
semipmts_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
share_text = DoubleVar()
share_label = Label(app, text='Sharing', font=('bold', 12), pady=20)
share_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
share_entry = Entry(app, textvariable = share_text)
share_entry.grid(row=3, column=0)
summary_dir_text = StringVar()
summary_dir_label = Label(app, text='Summary Path', font=('bold', 12), pady=20)
summary_dir_label.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
summary_dir_entry = Entry(app, textvariable = summary_dir_text )
summary_dir_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

summary_button =Button(app, text='Get Summary', width=15, command = df.get_data())
summary_button.grid(row=15, column=1, pady=20)


app.title('Loan Level')
app.geometry('500x500')

app.mainloop()

df = Loan(filename = filename_text.get(), settle_date=settle_date_text.get(), 
  semipmts=semipmts_text.get(), share=share_text.get(), summary_dir=summary_dir_text.get())
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you put before `mainloop()` then it runs it before you even see window because `mainloop()` creates window and runs all functions in window.  If you run it after `mainloop()` then it runs after you close window and some elements can be `destroy()` and remove from memory. I think your button should run function which runs `Loan()` and `df.get_data()`

Answer (score 1):

If you put `df = Loan()` before `mainloop()` then it runs it before you even see window because `mainloop()` creates window and it runs all functions in window - so you will get empty strings from widgets `filename_text, settle_date_text, semipmts_text, share_text, summary_dir_text`

If you run it after `mainloop()` then it runs after you close window and some elements can be `destroy()` and remove from memory. And `df` will not exists so you can run `command=df.get_data` (by the way: it has to be without `()`)

You have to run in function executed by button

```
def get_summary():
    df = Loan(filename=filename_text.get(), settle_date=settle_date_text.get(), semipmts=semipmts_text.get(), share=share_text.get(), summary_dir=summary_dir_text.get())
    df.get_data()

# ...code ...

summary_button = Button(app, text='Get Summary', width=15, command=get_summary)   # function's name without `()`
```